# На каких языках программировать нейронные сети?

Tags: нейронные-сети

Я хочу научиться программировать нейронные сети. Какие языки для этого подходят?

Comment: Я с ними не работал, но часто по `python` вижу тут вопросы, связанные с ними

Answer (score 1):

На данный момент больше всего подходят Python и R. Советую начать с Python, обучиться основам, а потом браться за нейросети. Прикреплю пару книг на своё усмотрение

[Книга по Python](https://ru.pdfdrive.com/python-%D0%AD%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81-%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81-e187730201.html). Если уже знакомы с каким-то языком, то пойдёт легко

[Нейросети на Keras и TensorFlow от создателя Keras](https://ru.pdfdrive.com/%D0%93%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0-python-e184715133.html)

Comment: У меня в наличии книга "Простой Python. Современный стиль программирования". Для начинающего пойдёт?

Comment: @Nicolaus прочитайте, попробуйте. В интернете много книжек и курсов по питону и машинному обучению (не говоря уже о статистике, теорверу). Каждому своё

Comment: Читали ли вы книги Марку Лутца?

Comment: @Nicolaus не довелось, но отзывы друзей хорошие

Comment: Возьмусь за неё после книги Любановича

Answer (score 0):

Нейронные сети можно программировать (и реально программируют) буквально на всем - от Python до Java. От С++ до Julia.  От JavaScript до Go.

Важно с самого начала уяснить, что нейросети - это алгоритм, а язык программирования  -  лишь средство его реализации.  Хотите понять, что такое нейросети - изучайте именно нейросети. И тут один набор книг и источников.

Хотите научиться программировать на любом языке -  учитесь программировать на любом языке. 
Хотите на Python -  миллион книг.

А когда разберетесь "что" делать (т.е. поймете, что такое нейросеть) перейдете к шагу "как этот делать" на выбранном вами языке.

Попытка ускорить процесс, пытаясь смешать в кучу одно с другим как правило приводит к плачевному финалу. Что мы имеем "удовольствие" наблюдать даже на этом форуме на потоке совершенно "безумных" вопросов от недоучек, решивших включить турборежим обучения.

Comment: Книга "Грокаем алгоритмы" по Python пойдёт?

Comment: Для тех, кто знает Python - в качестве введения подойдет.

Comment: Что скажете о книгах Марка Лутца по python?

Comment: Вы  так и не прочитали, что я вам написал. А жаль. Лутц - это  реально отличные книги. Для тех, кто ставить задачу (хотя-бы в перспективе) стать Python-программистом. Как-то очень смутно представляю себе новичка, решившего одновременно осиливать нейросети и Лутца. Можете, впрочем, попробовать набить своих шишек.  Потом расскажете впечатления -  на каких страницах книг остановились.